# NopCommerce append numeric on an existing slug

Tags: c#, nopcommerce, slug

In NopCommerce, an incremental value of a slug is added if such slug already exists (either adding or updating). An existing slug "**product-name-here**" becomes "**product-name-here-1**". And if I add the same slug then it now becomes "**product-name-here-2**".

I couldn't seem to find at "UrlRecordService.cs" file that handles the appending of numeric value at the end of every slug.

Any help is much apprediated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's implemented in `ValidateSeName` extension method inside [SeoExtensions](https://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Libraries/Nop.Services/Seo/SeoExtensions.cs) class.

```
    public static string ValidateSeName<T>(this T entity, string seName, string name, bool ensureNotEmpty)
         where T : BaseEntity, ISlugSupported
    {
        if (entity == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

        //use name if sename is not specified
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(seName) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
            seName = name;

        //validation
        seName = GetSeName(seName);

        //max length
        //For long URLs we can get the following error:
        //"the specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters"
        //that's why we limit it to 200 here (consider a store URL + probably added {0}-{1} below)
        seName = CommonHelper.EnsureMaximumLength(seName, 200);

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(seName))
        {
            if (ensureNotEmpty)
            {
                //use entity identifier as sename if empty
                seName = entity.Id.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                //return. no need for further processing
                return seName;
            }
        }

        //ensure this sename is not reserved yet
        string entityName = typeof(T).Name;
        var urlRecordService = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IUrlRecordService>();
        var seoSettings = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<SeoSettings>();
        int i = 2;
        var tempSeName = seName;
        while (true)
        {
            //check whether such slug already exists (and that is not the current entity)
            var urlRecord = urlRecordService.GetBySlug(tempSeName);
            var reserved1 = urlRecord != null && !(urlRecord.EntityId == entity.Id && urlRecord.EntityName.Equals(entityName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
            //and it's not in the list of reserved slugs
            var reserved2 = seoSettings.ReservedUrlRecordSlugs.Contains(tempSeName, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            if (!reserved1 && !reserved2)
                break;

            tempSeName = string.Format("{0}-{1}", seName, i);
            i++;
        }
        seName = tempSeName;

        return seName;
    }
```